# ordenar una pila en java sin usar ciclos ni arreglos

Tags: java

estoy estudiando estructura de datos y estoy intentando ordenar una serie de nuemeros enteros dentro de mi pila, pero el problema es que no se como poder ordenarlos sin usar nungun ciclo ni arreglo, alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo por favor.

```
public class Pila {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> pila = new Stack<Integer>();
    pila.push(5);
    pila.push(9);
    pila.push(2);
    pila.push(3);
    pila.push(500);

}
```

esto solo es un pequeno vistazo del contenido de mi pila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza la función [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Ésta se encarga de ordenar alfabéticamente la lista que le pases por argumento.

```
public class Pila {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> pila = new Stack<Integer>();
    pila.push(5);
    pila.push(9);
    pila.push(2);
    pila.push(3);
    pila.push(500);
    
    Collections.sort(pila);
    System.out.println(pila); //resultado [2, 3, 5, 9, 500]

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el dato, si me sirvio.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la única manera que se me ocurre es usando recursión. Sin embargo, con un gran número de datos esto puede consumir más recursos. Partiendo de tu ejemplo, debes hacer dos funciones que harán la recursión.

```
void ordenarPila(Stack<Integer> s) {
    // checamos si no esta vacía la pila
    if(!s.isEmpty()) {
        int tmp = s.pop();  // obtenemos el ultimo valor
        ordenarPila(s);   // hacemos la recursión
        insertarOrdenado(s, tmp);  // agregamos el valor que removimos
    }
}

void insertarOrdenado(Stack<Integer> s, int tmp) {
    // Caso base: la pila esta vacia o sin iniciar
    // se inserto un valor mayor al tope de la pila
    if (s.isEmpty() || tmp > s.peek()) {
        s.push(tmp);
        return;
    }

    // Si el tope es mayor, se remueve y se hace la recursión
    int temp = s.pop();
    sortedInsert(s, tmp);

    //agrega de vuelta el tope que removimos anteriormente
    s.push(temp);
}
```

En tu programa solo tienes que mandar a llamar la función `ordenarPila()` mandando como argumento la pila que declaraste.